# ¿Como ejecutar algo parecido a WindowClosing con JasperViewer?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Si se usa WindowClosing para correr un evento en un jframe al cerrarlo,
¿Cómo podría correr un evento con jasperviewer al cerrar su ventana?, 
La razón de esto es el de preguntar al usuario si quiere generar un pdf del jasper o solo cerrarlo.

Aquí mi código:

PS: He intentado correr un if pero no funciona por que se ejecuta una sola vez lo sé.

```
int codigo = Integer . parseInt(dia + "" + mes + "" + año + "" + valor);
            //
            JasperViewer jasperViewer = new JasperViewer(jprint, false);//false evita que se cierre toda la aplicacion
    jasperViewer . setTitle("Cotizacion ");
            jasperViewer . setVisible(true);
            //

            if (jasperViewer != null && jasperViewer . isVisible()) {
            } else {
                int dialogbutton = JOptionPane . showConfirmDialog(
                        null,
                        "Desea Guardar el reporte en pdf",
                        "Alerta",
                        JOptionPane . YES_NO_OPTION
                    );
            if (dialogbutton == 0) {
                JasperExportManager . exportReportToPdfFile(
                    jprint,
                    "C:\\Users\\HENRY\\Documents\\Cotizacion" + Fecha + valor + ".pdf"
                );
                File go = new File("C:\\Users\\HENRY\\Documents\\Cotizacion" + Fecha + valor + ".pdf");
            Desktop . getDesktop() . open(go);
            }}
```

Comment: Henry bienvenido a Stackoverflow. No logro entender tu planteamiento... ¿Preguntar al usuario si quiere generar un PDF del Jasper o solo cerrarlo? ¿Qué quieres decir con eso?

Comment: Holaa, mira en mi proyecto cuando invoco a Jasperviewer me sale un visor predeterminado jasper de mi reporte, el problema esta en como podria correr un JOptionPane . showConfirmDialog cuando el usuario cierre este visor y decida si quiere que el susodicho reporte sea generado en un pdf o no haga nada por que quiere modificarlo.                 Lo unico similar que se me ocurre es el windowClosing del JFrame que puedes utilizar para preguntar si quieres de verdad cerrar la ventana.

Comment: Henry no le veo mucho sentido a eso. Generalmente tú generas un reporte para verlo en pantalla o para imprimirlo ¿no?. El reporte se puede generar directamente en PDF y mostrarlo en la ventana de `JasperViewer`. El usuario lo verá y/o imprimirá si quiere. Y si necesita modificar algo, cerrará el Viewer, modificará lo que tenga que modificar y volverá a generar el reporte. Lo de preguntarle si quiere generar un PDF o no al pulsar el botón `Cerrar`  no tiene ningún sentido, ni es lógico, el botón cerrar es para cerrar.

Comment: Lo se, pero desde mi punto de vista como desarrollador simplista deseo que mi aplicacion guarde con un solo "click" estos pdf con un codigo unico en una ruta predeterminada ,PERO, solo los pdf correctos, ya que se da el caso que un reporte sea erroneo, quizas me falto agregar que es una aplicacion de cotizaciones.Aun asi de no haber posibilidad puedo agregar un boton en el frame que haga eso pero tengo el capricho de hacer lo mas simple posible mis aplicaciones y menos botones es una nesecidad interior . Aun asi gracias por responderme Cedano  !(─‿‿─)!